# MongoDB server getting disconnected

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the following error while running `mongod` in the terminal(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

```
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting: pid=4810 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Rohan
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.8
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version:ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-08-16T13:32:14.690+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-08-16T13:32:14.717+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
2016-08-16T13:32:14.717+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2016-08-16T13:32:14.717+0530 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: This can be relative to user rigths

Comment: & how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue myself, by deleting the mongodb-27017.sock file . I ran the service after deleting this file, which worked fine. However, I am still not sure the root cause of the issue. The output of the command ls - lat /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock is now

srwx------ 1 mongodb nogroup 0 Apr 23 06:24 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

Comment: After deleting mongodb-27017.sock, I'm getting this:exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

Comment: Try to restart mongo service

Comment: Also if you will have this error again try to execute this command 
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair

Comment: I tried this & runs without error, but it is stopping at waiting for connections on port 27017